# Display data for each day in a week column wise

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with rows ID, Data, Date. I need to generate a weekely report for each ID as rows and data corresponding to each ID on all the days of the week

Report should have the columns: 
ID , Monday_Data, Tuesday_Data, Wednesday_Data, Thursday_Data, Friday_Data

My Table is form below:

```
ID  DATA            DATE
01  D1              08/06/2019
01  D2                08/05/2019
01  D3             08/08/2019
```

Report should be as below:
[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVJgc.png)

Please help me in writing query to get that report as shown

Comment: Google PIVOT in oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend not using reserved words for column names. To create a test table, I had to put DATE within double quotes; this is not a way to make friends among maintenance developers and DBAs.

I also recommend, for future questions, to provide test data that we can use to test and demonstrate our answers. For example:

```
create table t(ID,DATA,"DATE") as
select '01','D1', to_date('08/06/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
select '01','D2', to_date('08/05/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
select '01','D3', to_date('08/08/2019', 'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual;
```

Finally, I recommend telling us what version of the Oracle database you are using.

My answer here uses the PIVOT clause, which is available starting in version 11.1. An inline view turns the date into a day of the week, then PIVOT turns rows into columns.

```
select * from (
  select id, data, to_char("DATE", 'fmDay') weekday from t
)
pivot(max(data) for weekday in (
  'Monday' as "Monday_Data",
  'Tuesday' as "Tuesday_Data",
  'Wednesday' as "Wednesday_Data",
  'Thursday' as "Thursday_Data",
  'Friday' as "Friday_Data"
));

ID   Monday_Data   Tuesday_Data   Wednesday_Data   Thursday_Data   Friday_Data   
01   D2            D1                              D3
```

Best regards,
Stew Ashton

Answer (score 0):

Below approach works in hive

```
create table sqql
 (id string , 
data string ,
 datee string );

insert into sqql values 
('01','D1','2019-08-06'),
('01','D2','2019-08-05'),
('01','D3','2019-08-08');

select 
id , 
collect_set(monday)[0] as mon ,
 collect_set(tuesday)[0] as tue, 
collect_set(wednesday)[0] as wed,
collect_set(thursday)[0] as thu , 
collect_set(friday)[0] as fri, 
collect_set(saturday)[0] as sat,
collect_set(sunday)[0] as sun
 from ( select id,
case when extract(dayofweek FROM datee)=1 then data end as sunday,
case when extract(dayofweek FROM datee)=2 then data end as monday,
case when extract(dayofweek FROM datee)=3 then data end as tuesday,
case when extract(dayofweek FROM datee)=4 then data end as wednesday,
case when extract(dayofweek FROM datee)=5 then data end as thursday,
case when extract(dayofweek FROM datee)=6 then data end as friday,
case when extract(dayofweek FROM datee)=7 then data end as saturday
from sqql ) x 
group by id;
```